# Android and Remote PHP Server on Eclipse

Tags: android, mysql, sdk, adt, remote-server

I am completely new to remote server. There is an eclipse which remote systems is installed on it. I want to have an android project and then use the remote systems to connect to PHP server and use MySQL data. I have installed android ADT and SDK on this Eclipse which has Remote system on it. Did I do a right thing? How should I connect between Android App and remote server? Is there any manual about it?

Comment: `use the remote systems to connect to PHP server` ?? Please clarify what you have in mind with 'remote system'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as i understand question, you're interest in how to work with remote database from the Android application. For that is important to ask what platform you are going to use as server side PHP,JAVA, .NET? And according to answer it is possible to suggest nice tutorial.

It is quite good tutorial for beginning.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I want to know how to use android Project in the Eclipse which Remote Server is installed on it. Like local host and different ips.

Comment: In my eclipse there are Local, some servers with IPs. I think that I have to add my project in Local>Workspace. But then How to run this android project? This is not a usual Eclipse which I have programmed on it. Cause Remote server is installed on it.

Comment: `In my eclipse there are Local, some servers with IPs.` ??? Please clarify. Which ones? Which ips? `Remote server is installed on it.` ???

Comment: RSE in installed on my Eclipse. I have added an android project under Local>local files>workspace in eclipse RSE. How can I run android Project? Is my android project in a right directory? What should I write in local shell in order to run my android project?